# Do Italian frame sets use different sized components to bikes in the USA?

Tags: maintenance

I want to restore an Italian made bike but I am not sure if components I buy in the US will fit.

Comment: If you buy the right components, they will fit.  This means finding out exactly what you have.  It may be an Italian-named bike with conventional parts.  So bottom brackets especially may be threadded the opposite way.   Tell us more about the bike, and provide a couple of close up, well lit and clear photos.

Comment: Historically, the Italians have always done things differently -- different BB standards, etc.  But it's likely that in the past 20 years or so they've adopted the global (ie, Shimano) standards to some degree.

Comment: You can still get parts for Italian bikes, but they'll be more expensive than the usual parts, and you need to know that you need them (which means, measure everything to check if its an Italian standard or not).

Answer (score 3):

Some Italian bikes have a metric BB thread but I have a Bianchi that has the standard BSA imperial thread so it's very difficult to tell unless you have thread measuring gauges. There are still a lot of BB assembly manufacturers making Italian threaded versions. As for any other parts they'll have standard European or Japanese (DIN or ISO) metric threads. Steerer tubes are usually imperial and seat posts invariably have a metric equivalent to the imperial parts.